# How to get Lat/Lng from a Geometric property?

Tags: google-maps, geometry, latitude-longitude

Alright, I am very new to GIS, my question might not even make sense, but help me get through this.

I have this JSON data of some fields which have this geometry property:

```
"geometry": {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-9808308.55,4693529],[-9808325.985,4693527.669],[-9808334.548,4693526.964],[-9808333.404,4693527.538],[-9808328.685,4693530.385],[-9808326.444,4693532.015],[-9808322.29,4693535.601],[-9808318.672,4693539.547],[-9808315.572,4693543.916],[-9808313.091,4693548.874],[-9808311.481,4693554.29],[-9808310.817,4693559.639],[-9808310.73,4693566.446],[-9808307.432,4693534.353],[-9808308.55,4693529]]]},
```

So these co-ordinates are, obviously, not Lat-Lng's of the field co-ordinates which is what I want when I have to project them on Google Maps. How should I go about this? Can we get Lat/Lng of these co-ordinates without knowing which the transformation formula which had been applied on it? (I even don't know these field co-ordinates belong to which region!)

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) formated geometry  and the ordering of x and y are important.

> Point coordinates are in x, y order (easting, northing for projected coordinates, longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates):

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks! Is there a way I could know which transformation algorithm has been applied to get these co-ordinates from their respective Lat/Lngs? And would Google Maps API would be able to plot these polygons on the map if I pass it by just specifying the transformation, or do I need to write the interface method myself?